# Display current user data from firebase database (web)

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

***Hello!***

*I've been working on a web project where a user is able to sign up and log in. I wanted to add a profile too, where some info they've provided could be diplayed on the page 'Profile'.*

*I've already used firebase auth (with email & password) and rt database to store extra info like 'Name', 'Bio', etc.*

> What I seem to not understand is how to **retrieve** the info that's
>   stored on the database and **display** it on a < p > tag on the
>   profile page.

I've already tried solutions from other questions asked in here but none seemed to work for me.

---

This is how my database is looking:

```
users:
|
+-uid1
 |
 +-Name
 |
 +-Gender..
|
+-uid2
 |
 +-Name
 |
 +-Gender..
```

---

Here is some code for the profile page:

> What i was trying to do here is get the current user that's logged
>   in and display the name on the profile - on a < p > tag that has an id=username.

```
    //getting reference to the apps
   const auth = firebase.auth();
   const database = firebase.database();
   //also creating table 'users' on database
   const rootRef = database.ref('users');

// ------------------------------------//

   //Check if signed in
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.

    database.ref('/users/'+ userId).on('value')
    .then(function(snapshot) {
      var snapVal = snapshot.val();
      displayName.innerHTML = snapVal.Name
      var name = diplayName
      document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = "Welcome: " + name + "!";
    })
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    window.location = "login.html"
  }
});
```

---

When I tested the code I got this error on the console:

```
Error: Query.on failed: Was called with 1 argument. Expects at least 2.
```

Also, I don't really know if I am using this function correctly.

Should I replace 'userId' with something else?

> database.ref('/users/'+ **userId**).on('value')

---

Thank you for reading this and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting `userId` to anything yet. When your `onAuthStateChanged` callback is called, and `user` has a value, you know that a user is signed in. At that point you can get that user's UID by doing `user.uid`.

So something like:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    database.ref('/users/'+ user.uid).once('value')
    .then(function(snaphot) {
      document.getElementById("username").innerText = "Welcome: " + snapshot.val().Name;
    })
  } else {
    window.location = "login.html"
  }
});
```

The `Name` in `snapshot.val().Name` needs to match whatever property from the user node in the database you want to show

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! You were right about the uid but even after adding the changes I kept getting the same error on the console. I've realized that what was causing it to happen was that I had to define the 'on' function a bit differently - which I'll share in here just in case somebody else needs it - But if I didn't add the part you suggested it wouldn't have worked anyways so I'll mark your answer as correct! `//I had to add value and function(snapshot) on the same () using a comma. That fixed it!
    database.ref('/users/'+ user.uid).on('value', function(snapshot) {`

Comment: Also, would you mind if I asked another question? I've asked the user to paste an image url on a text field for their profile pic, and this info is stored on the database too. I've added a placeholder image on the profile.html how can I replace this placeholder with the url they've provided? Or is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: On the `on()` syntax: sorry about missing that. While your updated syntax is indeed correct, you'll actually want to use `once()` to just read the value once. I just updated my answer to show that.

Comment: Updating the profile image in the HTML would be something like `document.getElementById("imageElement").src = urlToImg`

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll add that small change to my code!